# joining more than two tables in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

i want to join 4 tables with hibernate. i write following code for fetch name , teacher detail and schedules of course:

```
public Student getStudentDetail(int studentId) {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", studentId));
        criteria.setFetchMode("attends", FetchMode.JOIN);
        Criteria attendCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("attends", "attend")
                .setFetchMode("course", FetchMode.JOIN);
        Criteria courseCriteria = attendCriteria.createCriteria("course", "course")
                .setFetchMode("scheduleList", FetchMode.JOIN);
        Criteria scheduleCriteria = courseCriteria.createCriteria("scheduleList", "schedule");
        return (Student) scheduleCriteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

the query created by hibernate is to get detail is:

```
select
    this_.id as id1_4_4_,
    this_.code_melli as code_mel2_4_4_,
    this_.email as email3_4_4_,
    this_.mobile as mobile4_4_4_,
    this_.name as name5_4_4_,
    this_.phone as phone6_4_4_,
    this_.register_date as register7_4_4_,
    attend1_.course_id as course_i1_1_0_,
    attend1_.student_id as student_2_1_0_,
    attend1_.score as score3_1_0_,
    course2_.id as id1_2_1_,
    course2_.cluster as cluster2_2_1_,
    course2_.code as code3_2_1_,
    course2_.end_date as end_date4_2_1_,
    course2_.name as name5_2_1_,
    course2_.salary as salary6_2_1_,
    course2_.start_date as start_da7_2_1_,
    course2_.students as students8_2_1_,
    course2_.teacher_id as teacher10_2_1_,
    course2_.tuition as tuition9_2_1_,
    schedule3_.course_id as course_i1_2_6_,
    schedule3_.course_id as course_i1_3_6_,
    schedule3_.day as day2_3_6_,
    schedule3_.course_id as course_i1_3_2_,
    schedule3_.day as day2_3_2_,
    schedule3_.endt as endt3_3_2_,
    schedule3_.start as start4_3_2_,
    teacher8_.id as id1_5_3_,
    teacher8_.code_melli as code_mel2_5_3_,
    teacher8_.email as email3_5_3_,
    teacher8_.mobile as mobile4_5_3_,
    teacher8_.name as name5_5_3_,
    teacher8_.phone as phone6_5_3_,
    teacher8_.register_date as register7_5_3_ 
from
    public.students this_ 
inner join
    public.attend attend1_ 
        on this_.id=attend1_.student_id 
inner join
    public.courses course2_ 
        on attend1_.course_id=course2_.id 
left outer join
    public.schedule schedule3_ 
        on course2_.id=schedule3_.course_id 
left outer join
    public.teachers teacher8_ 
        on course2_.teacher_id=teacher8_.id 
where
    this_.id=?
```

but it has problem:

setFetchMode method dont work. beacuse program throw following exception:

threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.

Comment: Can you please show what query it is creating or what exception it is throwing

Comment: @ishantgaurav i add query and exception o my question

Comment: why do you think setFetchMode is not working and Null Pointer exception is not because of the not having the relevant tuple . It seems to me that your query is working and it is giving Null data in return

Comment: setFetchMode dont work beacause when i set the  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) program throw exception and just work with EAGER.@ishantgaurav

Comment: in debugging all course without schedule have null value. their id and other fields are null